# Firebase query returning null even though data is there

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a query set up where it will search where age entered by user is in my database. For some reason, even though the age is in my database, it will still return as null.

If I enter 35 as the age, it will still print "NULL" even though 35 is one of the age in the database. How do I fix this?

[image]
Json File:

```
  {
  "data" : [ {
    "age" : 35,
    "agratio" : 0.9,
    "alb" : 3.3,
    "alkphos" : 187,
    "db" : 0.1,
    "diagonsis" : "yes",
    "gender" : 1,
    "sgot" : 18,
    "sgpt" : 16,
    "tb" : 0.7,
    "tp" : 6.8
  }, {
    "age" : 40,
    "agratio" : 0.9,
    "alb" : 3.3,
    "alkphos" : 187,
    "db" : 0.1,
    "diagonsis" : "no",
    "gender" : 1,
    "sgot" : 18,
    "sgpt" : 16,
    "tb" : 0.7,
    "tp" : 6.8
  } ],
  "users" : {
    "234234adfsdsf" : {
      "username" : "hey"
    },
    "BbZZCTIIcJdvCCU9og905kKVvo53" : {
      "email" : "andy55@yahoo.com",
      "username" : "andy"
    }
  }
}
```

Code:

```
@IBAction func onDiagnose(_ sender: Any) {
        let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://agetest.firebaseio.com/")
        let databaseRef = ref.child("data")
        databaseRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "age").queryEqual(toValue: String(ageTextField.text!)).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // if there is data in the snapshot reject the registration else allow it

            if (snapshot.value! is NSNull) {


               print("NULL")

            } else {
                print(snapshot.ref.parent?.key!)
                //get parent

            }


        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing a string (in your code) with a number in the database, and those are not the same. The solution is to parse the number in your code before passing it into `queryEqual(toValue: )`:

```
databaseRef
  .queryOrdered(byChild: "age")
  .queryEqual(toValue: Int(ageTextField.text)!)
  .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

Comment: Thanks, I got that fixed now. How do I check if all values (age, agratio, alb, alphos, gender, sgot, sgpt, and all the other ones) are equal to values entered by user? If it does, then I want it to return the parent, in this case "0". Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience working with the Fiebase Realtime Database, it doesn't take in an array of objects like what you have in your JSON file there.  I've had to format it simply as nested objects without any arrays.  Something more like:

```
"data" : {
 <someRandomKey1> : {
    "age" : 35,
    "agratio" : 0.9,
    "alb" : 3.3,
    "alkphos" : 187,
    "db" : 0.1,
    "diagonsis" : "yes",
    "gender" : 1,
    "sgot" : 18,
    "sgpt" : 16,
    "tb" : 0.7,
    "tp" : 6.8
  }, 
<someRandomKey2> : {
    "age" : 40,
    "agratio" : 0.9,
    "alb" : 3.3,
    "alkphos" : 187,
    "db" : 0.1,
    "diagonsis" : "no",
    "gender" : 1,
    "sgot" : 18,
    "sgpt" : 16,
    "tb" : 0.7,
    "tp" : 6.8
  } 
},
```

To determine if this might have something to do with the issue you're experiencing, you might want to go into the Firebase Console, and look at the data in your Realtime Database via the web interface to see if it's saving the way you expect or not.

Comment: Yeah the json file looks weird. My web interface looks right. I updated my question to attach a web view of it.